# how to open frame2 from another frame1 by clicking button on frame1 in net beans

Tags: java

i have created two frames in a project in net beans named library.java and newCustomer.java and i have a button in library den what would be the code to go to newCustomer by clicking the button("New Customer") in library??

Comment: i have jus designed labels textboxs n buttons i had to use connectivity of frames which im unaware of so din try anythinn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside you library.java create some method lets say

```
`public void addActionListnenersToComponents();`
```

which you call in your **library constructor**(Just a suggestion.. will depend on your implementation). Inside this you can have all your action listeners. For your scenario you can do something like

```
    JButton newCustomerButton = new JButton("Add Customer");
    newCustomerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newCustomer newCustomerFrame = new newCustomer();
            newCustomerFrame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: it says cannot find symbol class newCustomer

Comment: In your question you have specified you have a class newCustomer which extends JFrane. Please provide the code you have tried in your question so we can assist you in a better way.

Comment: kk .. i have created a project in net beans and den two files ie two new frames called library.java and newCustomer.java (dey r present in two diff tabs) so d newCustomer class is nt in library its in diff tab so if i try ur code in library it dsnt get newCustomer class .

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler of the button click (for some button visible in `library`) simply initialize the `NewCustomer` object and then set its visibility to `true`. This will show one Frame (`NewCustomer`) at the click of the button from `library`).

You might want to have some mechanisms which control how many frames are generated though.